# resizing and redrawing datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I uses datagridview for show query results from database which may have 0 to x number of rows.
So I made calculation to calculate size of underlaying form and my datagridview dependable on number of matched rows.
Underlying form is transparent and all of that looks like user control what appears and works just fine.

But here is one issue:
Every time datagrid have to grow, black square in that area is showed before datagrid is filled, what is not nice and surely unwanted.

Can I do something usual to avoid this?
Did datagridview have some mechanism to freze it and show data when populating is finished?
Or what else to do?

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim tw As Integer = 0
    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim sqlText As String
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = Nothing
    Dim btCommand As OdbcCommand = Nothing
    Dim mCmd As OdbcCommand = Nothing
    Dim mCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    If Trim(TextBox1.Text).Length Then
        mCon.ConnectionString = "Dsn=" + dbDsn + _
                                ";database=" + mydatabase + ";server=" + dbServer + ";port=" + dbPort + _
                                ";uid=" + dbUser + ";pwd=" + dbPass
        Try
            mCon.Open()
            btCommand = New OdbcCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION", mCon)
            sqlText = "SELECT dtbl_id, name... etc... FROM mytable WHERE name ILIKE '%" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & "%' ORDER BY name LIMIT 128"
            mCmd = New OdbcCommand(sqlText, mCon)
            reader = mCmd.ExecuteReader()
            While (reader.Read())

                Dim t_kol, t_ci As String
                If reader.GetValue(4) - reader.GetValue(5) = 0 Then
                    t_kol = "- "
                Else
                    t_kol = FormatNumber((reader.GetValue(4) - reader.GetValue(5)), 2)
                End If
                t_ci = FormatNumber(reader.GetValue(3))

                With DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), _
                                                          reader.GetValue(1).ToString(), _
                                                          reader.GetValue(2).ToString(), _
                                                          t_kol, _
                                                          t_ci, _
                                                          reader.GetValue(6).ToString(), _
                                                          reader.GetValue(7).ToString})
                    n = n + 1
                End With
            End While
            btCommand = New OdbcCommand("END TRANSACTION", mCon)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Finally
            reader.Close()
            reader.Dispose()
            btCommand.Dispose()
            mCmd.Dispose()

            If n < 1 Then
                DataGridView1.Height = 0
                DataGridView1.Height = DataGridView1.Height + DataGridView1.Top
            End If

        End Try
        mCon.Close()
        mCon.Dispose()
    End If

    If n < 1 Then
        DataGridView1.Height = 0
    Else
        DataGridView1.Height = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + (n * DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height) + 2
    End If

    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToScreen(DataGridView1.Location)
    If p.Y + DataGridView1.Height >= My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height Then DataGridView1.Height = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height - p.Y

    tw = totalwidth + (Math.Abs(CInt(DataGridView1.Controls(1).Visible)) * CInt(DataGridView1.Controls(1).Width))
    DataGridView1.Width = tw + 2
    With Me
        .Width = tw + 4
        .Height = DataGridView1.Height + DataGridView1.Top
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you did code your thing, but did you try to put something like

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = someList
DataGridView1.DataBind()
If DataGridView.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToScreen(DataGridView1.Location)
    If p.Y + DataGridView1.Height >= My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height Then
        DataGridView1.Height = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Height - p.Y
        tw = totalwidth + (Math.Abs(CInt(DataGridView1.Controls(1).Visible)) * CInt(DataGridView1.Controls(1).Width))
        DataGridView1.Width = tw + 2
    With Me
        .Width = tw + 4
        .Height = DataGridView1.Height + DataGridView1.Top
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

in your methods?

As I said, I don't know how you coded your program so don't get me wrong or don't bother if it seems stupid to you.. ;)

EDIT : I changed the code. See what I was meaning, sorry if I wasn't really clear.

The thing is, you should draw your point only once some rows have been added to the DataGridView so I put some of your code in a If block. Don't bother my DataSource and DataBind part, I just wanted to clarify the point of my If block.

Comment: Still can't get solution. Even white square in back instead of black one?

Comment: Your code works exact same as mine. After many tryings I have to conclude that this weird behaviour is connected more with windows way of drawing "transparent" controls than with my code. But also here should be a way to avoid/mask/hide those problems. Any further idea is welcome.